# How to extract values in between parenthesis from a .gz file using read_csv method

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to extract values inside first parenthesis from a `txt.gz` file while reading it using pandas `read_csv` method.

The records inside `txt.gz` looks like below one

```
2022-02-20 00:00:10.061 INFO  [140191547254528] - ocm_input [14] sending Requestcom.com.sdcm.RequestScore("6016293021","JKT","ID","AP","SUB","ID","AP","FOIGTW",1,"","EWF","ID","national",11163.568125276915,.5,.24,0,0,0,"JKT","SUB","","","OISS INDONESIA","N",0,1,"FOCIDIGTW","","","jms:WebSphere_MQ-default-sender")..............context(1,"main",true)
```

I'm looking for something like this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40305122/log-file-to-pandas-dataframe) but for `txt.gz` file. In this example the values are being extracted from a string using `StringIO` but I need to do that from a `.gz` file. Also looking for best possible way if any.

What I'm looking for is to get the below values in pandas dataframe.

`("6016293021","JKT","ID","AP","SUB","ID","AP","FOIGTW",1,"","EWF","ID","national",11163.568125276915,.5,.24,0,0,0,"JKT","SUB","","","OISS INDONESIA","N",0,1,"FOCIDIGTW","","","jms:WebSphere_MQ-default-sender")`

What I'm looking for :

```
pd.read_csv(gzfilepath, compression='gzip',header=None, sep='\s*\(', quotechar='"', names=column_names,nrows=1000)
```

But I'm unable to read it that way. All I want is to extract values inside parenthesis while reading the `.gz` file

Comment: What code do you have so far? It looks like you already have read the file and the problem is just extracting the part between the parentheses. You can use the `re` module for that.

Comment: please be more clear, you only want manipulate the file name, or the content of `txt.gz`, and try to give some examples.

Comment: @LeiYang, question edited. I want the content of the file the values inside parenthesis read in pandas dataframe.

Comment: @JanWilamowski, I want to do that while reading the file in `read_csv` using `BytesIO` or `StringIO`

Comment: I would advise against using `read_csv` to read something that clearly isn't a CSV file. Fix the input, then read it in normally.

Comment: @JanWilamowski, I can read `.gz` using `read_csv` but looking for any direct options.

Comment: You mean like described here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566558/python-read-lines-from-compressed-text-files

Comment: @JanWilamowski, yes I will use this way if there is no direct option from `read_csv`